# Source for a LoopingSelector for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have been looking at nice, 3 part series about LoopingSelectors by Win phone Geek and unfortunately there is a missing source link for the first part on that website.
Can someone offer to please mail it to me or paste it in here, because I don't want to reinvent it? I would apppreciate it. Thanks.

Code for other demos for LoopingSelectors would be fine too.

Comment: Why not email that guy to fix the link?

Comment: The link is already fixed. I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

The `LongListSelector` is part of the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). You can download the [Source & Samples](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034#DownloadId=163012) for the November 2010 release, or download the [latest version](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), which includes fixes for various controls to enable applications to pass certification (there were issues with Back key press handling).

Comment: Go for the latest sources for now, until we get a new release out for the start of 2011!